# Create Magento Rest API

Tags: magento-1.9, rest-api, mobile, application

I have a shopping site in Magento now I would like to create its app in iOS and android mobile phone.So I need to create rest apis in Magento.. How I will do this.. I am new to this..

Comment: possibly this link can helo yo through http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/create_your_own_api.html

Comment: thank you for ur responase.. I would like to use rest api instead of soap.

Answer (score -1):

Magento2 provides a list of REST API's please find the link http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/rest/list.html

Comment: Thank you for your reply.. But  I would like to know how I create REST APIs Magento1.9 because I am new to WebServices...

Comment: This link have a sample php source for authentication do have a look http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/introduction.html#RESTAPIIntroduction-PreparingRESTAPIfortheThirdPartyApplication

Comment: I followed this tutorial too.. As a beginner this is very difficult for me...